# Accessing Ember component scope from block form?

Tags: ember.js

I want to let a user pass a custom text field, App.CustomTextField, in a Ember component using block form. However, that App.CustomTextField needs access to the component to manipulate its properties. How can I pass the component to the textfield using block form? I would like to pass the component as a property to App.CustomTextField, but how do I access the component's scope?

```
{{#blog-post}}
      {{view App.CustomTextField component=?}}
{{/blog-post}}
```

Comment: When using block form you're in the scope of the parent, so you wouldn't have access to the `blog-post` component instance.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking is not a very good idea. Components should expose properties. They are sort of like external settings that specify the component's behaviour.

Simply convert App.CustomTextField into a component and set all the required properties on it.

Comment: This is actually a much more contrived example than my actual use case, but I need to access the component's properties from a text field so what is the best way to do that?

Comment: As I said, such approach is a bad idea. There should be no logic in a text field.